# No launcher found

Tags: android, manifest, live-wallpaper

I have downloaded the code and imported, while I am running the code I got an error like No Launcher activity found! and The launch will only sync the application package on the device!.

I searched and got a solution that in manifest main and launcher action should be one after the other. I have done it but gain getting the same error and my app is not located in the emulator even though I am getting a message that "Wallpaper\bin\Wallpaper installed on device".

This is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.wallpaper"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
         android:minSdkVersion="8"
         android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper"
        android:required="true" >
    </uses-feature>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <service
            android:name="LiveWallpaperService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:label="Wallpaper Example "
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
                android:resource="@xml/mywallpaper" >
            </meta-data>
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Have to define launcher activity instead services.

Comment: with out service how a wallpaper works?

Comment: try to call your service from activity.

Comment: with in the activity tag I have to place the launcher, main and service?

Answer (score 0):

You Cannot Set the intent filter Launcher and Main to the service. Only Activity can be launched. Add an Activity to start the service in your project and set the launcher and main intent-filter to the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Define launcher activity like this,

```
<activity
    android:name=".yourlauncheractivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

& start your service in this launcher activity

Comment: then where I have to set the service?

Comment: can u jst tel me where I have to replace ur code in my file?

Comment: put is between  application tag

Comment: 11-24 08:42:39.939: E/AndroidRuntime(1299): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-24 08:42:39.939: E/AndroidRuntime(1299): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.wallpaper/com.example.wallpaper.LiveWallpaperService}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.wallpaper.LiveWallpaperService cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
11-24 08:42:39.939:E/AndroidRuntime(1299):at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
11-24 08:42:39.939:E/AndroidRuntime(1299):at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)

Comment: you can not pass service as launcher activity

Comment: you have to create activity in which you can start service

Comment: I am unable to paste my new activity how to do it. I will paste the full manifest here. please help me out

Comment: i just have pasted ur code after application and before service

Comment: public class LauncherActivity extends Activity{

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  
  Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, LiveWallpaperService.class);
     startService(serviceIntent);
 }
}

Comment: try this way, hope now you understand